# Give comment box for 'invalid flag' option

Tags: feature-request, comments, flag-dialog, declined-flags

When marking a flag as invalid, there should be a text box, so some logic can be given.

For example, it someone marked it 'not an answer', and I want to state why it is.

Comment: That's a pretty heavyweight request, considering that it's one-click right now. Who would see these comments, the original flagger? All the invalid flag does to them is drop their flag weight a little bit, unless they're abusive with the flags, in which case their flags eventually get ignored anyway. Would such a person listen to the little treatise I wrote about their invalid flag?

Comment: I don't think we're thinking of the same thing.  I'm talking about the dialog that comes up when I click on the `Flag or disagree` button.  It would then leave the comment as text, just like the `Not an answer` text is there now.

Comment: @Lance: Ah, I see. Being a moderator, I've never actually seen the "flag or disagree" dialog. This is a common problem; moderators see a view of the site that is somewhat different from ordinary users.

Comment: Prior to last week, the moderator dashboard said "[Name] disagrees with flag", one line per [name]. Since then it has been shortened to "deemed invalid by [name1], [name2], [name3]", so there isn't even any room for your text now.

Comment: @Robert, so where does the `other` text show then?

Comment: @Robert, I guess if there is no place to show the mod the text, it could at least be shown to other users so that they can make more informed decisions.

Comment: The flags are still one line per flag in the mod queue, but the disagrees have been crunched together.